# re-stringify a string in Android

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, stringify

I have a string that i'd like to stringify in Kotlin (Android), but it seems that `org.json.*` doesn't support taking a string and re-stringifying it, instead it always tries to parse it first.

```kotlin
val str = "test=\"123\""
val stringified = JSONObject(str).toString() // JSONException: Value a of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to `JSONObject`
```

The use case for this ability is passing data to JS inside a Webview in a secure manner.

```kotlin
val json = "test=\"123\""
webview.evaluateJavascript("window.onData(${json})")
// on the JS side it will look like this: window.onData(test="123")
// this is both invalid and insecure since it opens the door for raw JS injection
```

Any attempt to do it manually will result in an insecure and possibly invalid JS string
This example should **NOT** be used:
`val insecureJSON = "'${str.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\"", "\\\"").replace("'", "\'")}'"`

The desired behavior:

```kotlin
val json = jsonStringifyString("test=\"123\"")
webview.evaluateJavascript("window.onData(${json})")
// rendered JS: window.onData("test=\"123\"")
```

Is there an easy method for stringifying a string in Android?

Answer (score 3):

Ended up using the `JSONArray` class and removing the array wrapping to trick the class to stringify a plain string

```kotlin
fun jsonStringifyString(str: String): String {
    val jsonStr = JSONArray().put(str).toString()
    return jsonStr.substring(1, jsonStr.length - 1) // remove first and last char
}

val serializedData = jsonStringifyString("test=\"123\"");

webview.evaluateJavascript("window.onData(${serializedData})")
// rendered JS: window.onData("test=\"123\"")
```